# Time-series with non-synchronous trends. Any recommendation?

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation

Could you please help me with good approaches for non-synchronous time-series events? I have the following scenarios:

1. Time series data with number of events in a month (For instance: Medical events talking about hematology) represented by the **blue line**. Another time series data with the number of tickets per month in a call center with questions about the topic of the event, represented by the **orange line**.

[image: Events x Tickets open]

In the scenario above, it's observed that the number of tickets increase after events, but not in the same month. In other words, there is non-synchronous correlation between events and the number of tickets.

2. A Second scenario is when you have only the number of tickets per month (orange line) and the events are just a dummy variable that marks TRUE if an event took place at an specific month and FALSE if there was not an event in the respective month.

My questions are:

- What would be the best approaches to identify correlations in scenario 1 and 2?
- If I want to predict future months, is there some specific model for non-synchronous correlation?

Regards,

Rubens